# Math.ceil() issue. Am I losing my mind?

Tags: apex, bug

Ok I hope I am mising something here as I really don't want this to be a bug.

The following piece of code returns 2. Per my understanding of the ceiling functionality, the result should be 3 because 7/3 is roughly 2.33333 and the ceiling should return 3.

Is this a bug or am I missing something? Thanks.

```
Integer pageNumber = (Integer) Math.ceil(7/3);
```

This returns 2 and not 3 as expected.

It works fine on other input. For example:

```
Integer pageNumber = (Integer) Math.ceil(8/5);
```

This returns 2 as expected.

Comment: Not sure how you can get `Math.ceil(8/5) == 2`, because the following assertion passes for me: `system.assertEquals(1, Math.ceil(8/5))`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is probably because when you divide an `Integer` by an `Integer` you get an `Integer` back which has the same value as `Decimal.round(RoundingMode.DOWN)`.

```
system.assertEquals(1, 8/5);
system.assertEquals(8/5, (8.0/5).round(RoundingMode.DOWN);

system.assertEquals(-1, -8/5);
system.assertEquals(-8/5, (-8.0/5).round(RoundingMode.DOWN);

system.assertEquals(2, 7/3);
system.assertEquals(7/3, (7.0/3).round(RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

If you know you have `Integers` and you want to get their ceiling, you could do something like:

```
public static Integer ceiling(Integer x, Integer y)
{
    return Math.ceil(Decimal.valueOf(x).divide(y, /*digits*/ 1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for me as I need to divide  values returned by the Standardsetcontroller. getresultsize() and getpagesize(). Will treat them as decimals.

Comment: why doesn't (Integer) Math.ceil(8/5) return 1 though?

Comment: Integer division in most languages (including this one, I assume) is not `floor`, it's truncation.  There's a difference when the result is negative.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Good point. There is not even a corresponding [RoundingMode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm#apex_decimal_rounding_mode) for that. Interesting.

Comment: It would be `DOWN` in that table.  That naming is horrible; if this is the API you guys have to deal with, I'm sorry...

Comment: I don't know what the case is for Apex, but for Python, integer division does actually floor. If Apex truncates, you should probably use a language other than Python for your comparison.

Answer (score 16):

## Integer Division

In Apex Code, similar to Java, when there are two like numeric data types (e.g. both Integers), then they are calculated in a way that returns the same data type. Integers cannot store fractions, so when you do something like 7/3, the fraction is silently discarded. <strike>As far as I know, integer division works in the same for every programming language in the world where the result of integer arithmetic is an integer.</strike>In many languages where the result of two integers being divided together results in an integer, the fraction is often dropped entirely, although exceptions do exist (some perform rounding, instead).

## Parameter Promotion

You'll notice that there's no function Math.ceil that accepts an Integer. This means if you give it an integer, it will implicitly be cast to a floating point value before being processed by Math.ceil.

## Arithmetic Promotion

When two numbers are operated on using the standard operators (+, -, /, *), if one of those parameters are a floating point value, the other one will also automatically become a floating point value. Similarly, if a integer and a long were involved in an operation, both numbers become long, and the return type becomes long. So, the goal is to create a situation where a floating point is returned. For example, this results in the correct result:

```
Integer x = Math.ceil(7.0/3).intValue();
```

Here, the 7.0 indicates a floating point operation. You'd also get the same effect if you did this:

```
Decimal x = 7;
Integer y = 3;
Integer z = Math.ceil(x/y).intValue();
```

This behavior is well-defined, and mimics the behavior in Java. You can read more about automatic widening conversion in the Java documentation, as well as rules about integer division. You'll find that, while not explicitly mentioned in the Apex Code Developer's Guide (as far as I can tell), it obeys the same rules.

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant explanation. I should and will pay attention to my numeric data types especially when doing such operations with integers.

Comment: tats cool... so u r a Maths professor as well Mr Fox.. ;-)

Comment: ^^He indeed is...

Comment: "As far as I know, this is true for every programming language in the world where the result of integer arithmetic is an integer." Not true. The following two statements in PASCAL:  _WRITELN(9/2);_ and _WRITELN(9 DIV 2);_ will output 4.5 and 4 respectively. The "/" operator is an implicit floating point divide, and the DIV is an integer divide...

Comment: @HeartWare "...where the result of integer arithmetic is an integer." PASCAL's integer division happens to use a different token (DIV vs /), but doesn't invalidate this statement. The point was, if you ask for integer division, you lose the fractional, while if you ask for floating point, you get the fractional result. It's just that some languages, like PASCAL, are explicit (using two different tokens), while Apex Code uses one overloaded token to mean the same thing, just like C, C++, Java, C#, etc.

Comment: You won't get off that easily :-). You also stated "if there are two like numeric data types (e.g. both Integers), then they are processed in a way that returns the same data type.". This is not correct for PASCAL. There are two integers, but the result of using such two integers with the "/" operator is a floating point :-). When using it with "+", "-" or "*" you are correct, but not with the "/" operator :-)

Comment: @HeartWare Thanks. I believe this is just a matter of miscommunication. In Apex Code, the result of two integer values being divided is an integer, as is also done in Java, C, C++, and most languages in that family tree. In all languages that allow two integers to be divided and return an integer result, the fraction is discarded, as opposed to an exception being thrown or something different (as far as I know). I've updated that first paragraph to hopefully be more concise. Also, The paragraph was meant to lead on to implicit promotion of operands, like Java does.

Comment: In VB6, the result is more strange. The Runtime do a common round: 2.333 becomes 2 and 2.6666 becomes 3. To do arithmetic operations, you need to do a trick.

Comment: @AlexeiDimitriDinizCampos Fair enough, although Microsoft does tend to break traditional programming habits, especially in their BASIC languages. Regardless, it appears that the 30'ish languages I've used in life have just conditioned me to certain expected results.

Comment: @sfdcfox I mean as #HeartWare said, C Style rounding is not the only programming behavior. Anyway, the problem is #Richard N doesn't know the language basis or was tired when got the trouble.

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that when you divide an integer by an integer, it will always result in an integer.  So when you divide 7/3, it's actually returning 2, which is why the Math.ceil() function is returning 2.

Try doing `Math.ceil(7.0/3.0)`

Or you can use code such as:

```
Double seven = 7.0;
Double three = 3.0;
Integer pageNumber = (Integer)Math.ceil(seven/three);
```

BTW, the `Math.ceil(8/5)` should be returning 1, not 2.

Does anyone know where in the documentation it talks about this?  I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds writing it up.  This is exactly right.  You'll need to convert them to Decimal before dividing them.

Comment: Got it thanks. Same here...Found nothing on the documentation. It will be great to find something.