# Apex division shows zero value instead of correct value

Tags: apex

Why is totals showing zero for me in this snippet?

```
Integer stats;

Decimal total;

Integer cntOrg=60;

stats=200;
total = stats/cntOrg;

system.debug('Values for '+org+' is ' + total);
```

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [Math.ceil() issue. Am I losing my mind?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103159/math-ceil-issue-am-i-losing-my-mind/103163#103163) (confusion about Integer division).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `stats` and `cntOrg` should be in decimal then only output will be expected

```
Decimal stats;

Decimal total;

Decimal cntOrg=60;

stats=200;
total = stats/cntOrg;

system.debug('Values for '+org+' is ' + total);
```

If you divide integer datatype no. then result be in integer type.

So in your case `3` will be return not decimal numbers

If you divide Decimal datatype no.hen result be in Decimal type.

So in your case `3.33333333333333333333333333333333` will be return with decimal numbers

Comment: I just don't understand why? I am dividing an integer by another integer, only the result should be a decimal type, no?

Comment: @ApexN-u-b no if you divide 2 Integer type variable it will return only Integer number you will not get complete value. If you divide two `Decimal` no then it will return complete value .